# Vector constructor with two parameters is parsed as a function declaration

Tags: c++, parsing, stdvector, most-vexing-parse

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string sen = "abc def ghi jkl";
    std::istringstream iss(sen);

    std::vector<std::string>    // declaration in question
    vec(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

The compiler throws an error at the call to `std::copy`

`request for member 'begin' in 'vec', which is of non-class type...`

I can get around the error like this:

```
std::istream_iterator<std::string> it_begin(iss);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> it_end;
std::vector<std::string> vec(it_begin, it_end);
```

or by putting parentheses around each parameter, like this:

```
std::vector<std::string>
vec((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss)),
    (std::istream_iterator<std::string>()));
```

or even with the new uniform initialization in C++11:

```
std::vector<std::string> vec { /*begin*/, /*end*/ };
```

**Why is compiler parsing the declaration in the example as a function declaration?** I know about most vexing parse, but I thought that only happens with empty parameter lists.
I also wonder why the second workaround works.

Comment: GCC 4.6.1, if it matters. I also tried with comeau's online compiler.

Comment: Save yourself some typing with: `std::istream_iterator<std::string> it_begin(iss), it_end; std::vector<std::string> vec(it_begin, it_end);`

Comment: Well-formed, well-constructed and well-formatted question, on-topic and useful. Good job. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse(C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still the most vexing parse.

```
std::vector<std::string>                     // return type
vec(                                         // function name
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), // param 1: an iterator called (iss), or just iss
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>()     // param 2: unnamed function 
);                                           //          returning iterator
```

geordi says:

```
<tomalak> << ETYPE_DESC(vec); std::vector<std::string> vec(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
<geordi> lvalue function taking a istream_iterator<string, char, char_traits<char>, long> , a pointer to a nullary function returning a istream_iterator<string, char, char_traits<char>, long> , and returning a vector of strings
```

The crux of it, really, is that your parameter names can have parentheses around them (i.e. `iss` → `(iss)`) without altering the semantics of the declaration. Sometimes.

Use another set of parentheses *that also surround the type*, as you showed, to force that first parameter (and, consequently, the second) to be parsed as an expression rather than a declaration.

---

If it helps, also consider:

```
void foo(int (x)) {
   cout << x;
}

int main() {
   foo(42);
}
```

[Output is `42`](http://codepad.org/EKBJde2I).

Comment: @Als: The declaration is perfectly valid. However it is valid as both a vector declaration and as a function declaration, and _the standard says that the latter takes precedence_. It's your basic [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The OP is simply surprised that his declaration is a valid _function_ declaration, because of those parens around the name of the first argument.

Comment: Err..Maybe, Those parenthesis are redundant anyways one could put n no of those parenthesis and it would still work the same way.

Comment: @Als: Yes, exactly. That's the point. BTW the plural is "parentheses".

Comment: It makes sense to me now. You're right in your second comment, I was suprised it's a valid function declaration. Thanks.