# Converting a file content to string stream using istreambuf_iterator<>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm using the following code (using namespace std) to convert contents of a file to string.

**Code 1**

```
string fileToString(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!file) return "";
    string str(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
               (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    return str;
}
```

I find it weird that the code above works (I matched string::size() with actual file size found in Windows Explorer), but the following code doesn't:

**Code 2**

```
string fileToString(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!file) return "";
    string str(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
               istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return str;
}
```

Note the missing parentheses around second parameter. The second function gives the following compiler error:

> 1 error C2664:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,*Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'std::string (*_cdecl
>   *)(std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits>,std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,*Traits>
>   (*_cdecl *)(void))' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
>
> 2 IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from
>   "std::string (std::istreambuf_iterator>
>   file, std::istreambuf_iterator> (*)())"
>   to "std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator>"

I'm using **Visual Studio 2010**, Win32 Console Application on Windows XP SP3.

To my surprise, the following code compiles and works as expected:

**Code 3**

```
string fileToString(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!file) return "";
    return string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                  istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```

Why does **Code 2** produce compiler error?

Comment: I asked a very similar question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927939/vector-constructor-with-two-parameters-is-parsed-as-a-function-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does Code 2 produce compiler error?

Code 2 produces compilation-error because in Code 2, the following line declares a function:

```
string str(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
           istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

It declares a function. The function name is `str` . The return type is `string`. The function takes two parameters:

- first parameter is of type `istreambuf_iterator<char>`.
- second parameter is of type `istreambuf_iterator<char> (*)()` which is function pointer type which returns `istreambuf_iterator<char>` and takes no argument.

So in Code 2, you return a function called `str`. Since it cannot be converted into `string` which is the return type of the function `fileToString`, hence it gives compilation error.

In Code1 and Code3,  there is no such issue, hence they work as expected.