# Parenthesis around function call

Tags: c++

In the code snippet below, if I exclude the parenthesis around the second call to `std::istreambuf_iterator`, I get a compile error on the last line:

> left of .c_str() must have a class/struct/union.

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");;

std::string prog(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
prog.c_str();
```

What do these parentheses actually do? It seems to me that they should be able to be excluded.

Comment: Your instinct is good: they shouldn't be needed. But they are. As @LuchianGrigore says, it's to avoid the "most vexing parse", which is a bit of a glitch in the C++ grammar.

Comment: If you remove the parentheses, does `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` represent a function call, or an inline object instantiation?  That is the ambiguity the compiler sees, and thus the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vector constructor with two parameters is parsed as a function declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927939/vector-constructor-with-two-parameters-is-parsed-as-a-function-declaration) Exactly the same issue, just with vector instead of string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the parenthesis, this would be a case of [**most vexing parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It wouldn't declare a variable, but a function returning a `std::string`, called `prog` and taking those two types as parameters. If you attempt to call it afterwards, you'll get a linker error.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The thing is, I have no idea why. I gathered this is the cause from the error message :) If you (or anyone else) can explain, I'll remove this answer.

Comment: +1: didn't even know that had a name! only happens to you once :P

Comment: It can be parsed as a function taking a first argument of type `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` with name `file` (i.e. the parenthesis around `file` are optional, as in `int (a) = 5;`) and a second argument of type function pointer (after the decay) taking no arguments and returning a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`, this argument being unnamed. That is, it is equivalent to a declaration: `typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it; std::string prog( it file, it (*)() );`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ah, true. The `(file)` confused me. :)