# several different ways to read unsigned char from file

Tags: c++

I want to read unsigned char from file and have search many different ways to execute. But I don't know the reason why they work or don't work.

1.
`ifstream input(ios::in | ios::binary) //seems to not work, but why?`

I have set the `ios::binary` which supposed to prevent the conversion.

2.
`unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];`

`myfile.read((unsigned char *) buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);//error!fail`

`myfile.read((char *) buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);//work, the data type is unsigned char`

why do I have to convert it to `char*`?
The data stored in the array won't be converted to char not `unsigned char`?
What does it do during conversion?

3.
`vector`//it work but I don't know what it have done.

Comment: Your question does not actually describe anything going wrong. Do you observe different bits that you expect in any of these cases? How do you write the code for 'vector'

Comment: I use stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out | stringstream::binary); to get char in 1 but will get strange value.

Comment: I use unsigned char * in 2 which will prompt out error that conversion  
error. But I find it in the stackoverflow someone tpye it to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830936/reading-text-from-file-to-unsigned-char-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, the constructor also expects a file name. For example,

`ifstream input("myfile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);`

I believe you can omit the `ios::in`, as it is the default for `ifstream`.

And for the second part, `istream::read` expects a `char*` pointer (or some equivalent type). After reading the data, you can cast the elements to `unsigned char*`.

Answer (score 1):

The read function declares a prototype of 'char *'. This is just what some author did in the mists of time. It does not mean that any 'conversion' is going to take place. There is no 'conversion' from char * to unsigned char *, in any case; both are pointers to bytes, and any conversion semantics of I/O classes are going to be controlled by other factors.